# Why does the C++/CLI compiler get confused so easily with symbols?

Tags: c++-cli

Here is my code:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace Tests {
    ref class MyCollection : public IEnumerable<int> <----HERE!
```

The C# compiler, for instance, will recognize that the only `IEnumerable<T>` it has in those namespaces is from `System::Collections::Generic`. Why can't the C++/CLI compiler do the same? Unlesss I type its full name or at least `Generic::IEnumerable<int>`, it won't recognize it and will fire a C2872 error: ambiguous symbol.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your namespaces IEnumerable is ambiguous

MS define IEnumerable in both [System::Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and [System::Collections::Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which of the 2 do you want your code to use?

Comment: Erm, one is generic and the other isn't? Shouldn't be hard to pick which one to use, and furthermore, c# compiler isn't confused by it.

Comment: How does the compiler know *in advance* that it should pick the generic version? It hasn't yet parsed the `<int>`, and even when it does, it first needs to determine that the `<` is the beginning of a generic type, and not the `less than` operator. And it still has to parse C++ correctly, so they can't arbitrarily change how it parses code.

Comment: C# and C++ languages are different and so parse the code in different ways

Comment: So you mean c++ compiler doesn't read it as IEnumerable<int> but as IEnumerable (space) int?

Comment: I think it reads it as IEnumerable only and finds the definition from that

Comment: Well it must read the int, otherwise he wouldn't know which kind of generic it is, would it?